# Can I vent a 3 inch ABS sewer line with a 2 inch pipe?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I will be attaching 1-1/2" vent line from 4 different fixtures (shower, tub, 2 sinks) in the unfinished ceiling above bathroom and also if I can still use it as my main soil stack (2 inch) to protrude through the roof.

Comment: Feel free to edit and improve your Qs and As (and those of others) on SE.

Comment: I thought you needed a 2” vent for a tub/shower.